# Two States Continuous Time Markov Chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, poisson-process

This question comes from the book Continuous Time Markov Processes: An Introduction by Thomas Milton Liggett. It is exercise 2.8 and goes as follows:

Consider a process $X(t)$ with state space {0,1} that evolves as follows. If it starts at $0$, then the chain stays at $0$ for an exponential time with parameter $\beta$ and then moves to $1$. It then stays at $1$ for an exponential time with parameter $\delta$, and then moves back to $0$, and repeats, with analogous rules if it starts at $1$. Let $p_t(i,j)$ be the probability that $X(t)=j$ if $X(0)=i$.

a) Show that $$ p_t(0,1)=\int_0^t\beta e^{-\beta s}p_{t-s}(1,1)ds.$$

b) Use Laplace transforms to check that $$p_t(0,1)=\frac \beta {\beta+\delta}\left( 1-e^{-t(\beta+\delta)} \right).$$

I'm stuck on problem a). I tried to describe $p_t(0,1)=P(X(t)=1 \mid X(0)=0) $  as the probability of an odd number of "hits" (for a lack of a better word) of our (independent) exponential variables on $[0,t]$. But I don't know how to move forward with this probability. Because of our two (possibly different) parameters $\beta$ and $\delta$  I don't know how to compute this probability.

In addition, I'm not entirely sure this sort of "direct" computing is even necessary or if an identity of a Markov chain's transition function gives us a quicker solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Part (a) just wants you to condition on all possible times of the first transition from 0 to 1.  Use the law of total probability in integral form.  You only need consider one transition, you are over-thinking it to consider all possible odd-transitions.

Comment: Thank you, this is greatly helpful! Is there a similarly simple solution to b). I don't quite understand in what way I am to use Laplace Transforms.

Comment: This looks like a convolution equation, which could transform to a product.  But you would likely need to use a corresponding equation for transitions from 1 to 0 and also use $p_t(0,1) = 1 - p_t(0,0)$.

Comment: @FlorianEnte Have you maybe found a solution manual for the book?